# Elasticsearch Ingest pipeline -epoch_millis to date format

Tags: date, elasticsearch, data-ingestion

I am using the reindex API in ES 5.4.1, and I need to convert a long field(which represents a date) to a date field. So the source index looks like

```
"hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "twitter",
            "_type": "tweet",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "temp": 1496938873065,
               "message": "hello",
               "user": "joan"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```

temp has to be converted to a date object.

I want to use a processor,

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/p1
{
  "processors": [
      {
        "date" : {
        "field" : "temp",
        "target_field" : "updatedOn",
        "formats":["epoch_millis"],
        "timezone" : "Europe/Amsterdam"
      }
      }
    ]
}
```

But on trying to create this processor, I get an error

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "exception",
            "reason": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: p",
            "header": {
               "processor_type": "date"
            }
         }
      ],
      "type": "exception",
      "reason": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: p",
      "caused_by": {
         "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
         "reason": "Illegal pattern component: p"
      },
      "header": {
         "processor_type": "date"
      }
   },
   "status": 500
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `formats` parameter is wrong, you need to use `UNIX_MS` instead of `epoch_millis`, like this:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/p1
{
  "processors": [
      {
        "date" : {
        "field" : "temp",
        "target_field" : "updatedOn",
        "formats":["UNIX_MS"],
        "timezone" : "Europe/Amsterdam"
      }
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Nice, now creating the pipeline worked! Thank you so much Val, you are awesome. However there is a new problem now. When I try to apply the pipeline using the reindex API, using - POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    
    "index": "twitter"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "twitter",
    "pipeline": "p1"
  }
} I now get an exception "field [temp] of type [java.lang.Long] cannot be cast to [java.lang.String]"

Comment: You cannot use the same index as source and destination. Your destination must be another index with the new mapping.

Comment: I am using a different destination index

Comment: In your previous comment, they are both labelled `twitter`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I did use 2 differnet indices actually

Comment: I am actually trying to do it using java now, and script_fields. Still trying to get that working.

Comment: UNIX_MS did the job for me,  "formats" : ["epoch_millis", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"] = did not work.
"formats" : ["UNIX_MS", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"] = worked!